# Ddereferencing a pointer in linked list

Tags: c

I am getting an error in  `tail->next=(list)malloc(sizeof(node))`. Can someone tell me why? This code is being taught in one of the NPTEL videos and there it runs without any error.

Is there any problem in doing `tail->next=(list)malloc(sizeof(node))`?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main(){
    int choice,dat;

    typedef struct {
        int data;
        struct node* next; //pointer to a node
    }node;

    typedef  node* list;

    list head,tail;

    head=tail=NULL;

    printf("Enter Data? (1/0)\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    if(choice==1)
    {
        printf("Give Data?\n");
        scanf("%d",&dat);
        tail=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));
        tail->data=dat;
        tail->next=NULL;
        head=tail;

        printf("Enter Data? (1/0)\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);        
    }

    while(choice==1){
        printf("Give Data?\n");
        scanf("%d",&dat);

        tail->next=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));//showing error
        tail->next->data=dat;
        tail->next->next=NULL;
        tail=tail->next;
    }

    tail=head;

    while(tail!=NULL){
        printf("%d",tail->data);
        tail=tail->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for your code to successfully compile, you need to declare your node type as follows.

```
typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next; //pointer to a node
}node;
```

The reason behind this additional naming is due to node not being considered as declared until the end of the statement starting with typedef. That's why you need to name your struct as well, in order to be able to declare a pointer to its own type inside it.

Additionally, it seems that tail may be equal to NULL when you try the line that you mentioned to be problematic:

```
tail->next=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));//showing error
```

Unless the entered value read into the variable choice via scanf before the first if statement is 1, tail will be NULL when the first while loop starts, and trying to access(i.e. in order to assign the address of the allocated space) tail->next will be **equivalent to dereferencing NULL** address and then trying to access the field *next*, causing a segment violation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    struct node* next; // <-- problem
} node;
```

You're forward declaring `struct node` as a different type than your (anonymous) struct `node`.

You can fix this by giving the anonymous struct the name `node`, so that you can refer to it inside the definition:

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} node;
```

Now there's only one type named `node`.

---

Also your `main` function is missing a return type. It should be:

```
int main() {
```